# Is it possible to get access to click events from quill-mention?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I would like to redirect users from editor if they click on @**mention** (or #**tag**) elements provided by **quill-mention**. (Angular + ngx-quill + quill-mention).
Is it possible? If so, how?
Or do I need another, more sophisticated editor?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect user to another page or to another website? You can just wrap a mention with link and redirect user on click?

Comment: redirect to another page, not a site.

Answer (score 0):

You have mention-clicked event as per official documentation.

```
window.addEventListener('mention-clicked', (event) => { console.log('clicked: ', event) }, false);//handle the click event from here
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-mention/v/4.1.0#hover-and-click-example

The above is the link to quill-mention document